# @media print div: How to solve overlapping page text on header?

Tags: html, css

I am using @media to print a header on each page when printing a screen in page in Firefox. I have my css set up like this:

```
@media print {
    div.printDivHeader {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is the content of the second page overlaps with the print div header. (i.e., on the second page, the header doesn't force the page contents down, and so I get text written over text). Is there some way to handle this?

Comment: We would need the html and css of that second page, thanks

Comment: By the way, I am not sure you are aware but the current version of Firefox has a Print Preview function. Without this, one would have to either print to pdf or print to paper... both cumbersome options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something with `position: fixed;` never pushes static (or relative) content. Either there is styling to ensure they do not overlap... or they overlap.
See [this example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpht2/1/), which uses your css.

The problem lies somewhere else.
How does the header not overlap with the text in the first page? Do you have something pushing the text down? Margin-top? What?

Is it possible to share either the original or a simplified example? (You can use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).)

Comment: The problem is if I don't use position: fixed the header will not appear on every page

Comment: (Did you mean to post this comment to @Augus' answer?) Yes, I understand. From my point of view the problem is: something is pushing the content of the first page down, but not the content of other pages; that something is not the header; thus no changes to the header will help, and we should look into what else is doing the effect.

Comment: On the first page there is a H2 element with enough padding at the top that the overlap does not happen. Also, it appears that when I do this:@media print {
  div.printDivHeader {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  @page { 
    margin: 1cm;
    margin-top: 5cm; 
  }
} /* All margins set to 2cm */
... it works fine for the first page (margin as expected) but not for subsequent pages.

Comment: So it would never work on the other pages, as there is no H2 element - of course. It might work using margin-top as you set it... except that, according to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#allowed-pg-brk , `When a page break occurs here, the computed values of the relevant 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' properties are set to '0'.` The same is true for padding. I'm at a loss, no solution here.

Comment: I removed the h2 tag and still get the error. The margin works only on the first page.

Comment: Yes. I read all over the http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/ page and found nothing that I could manage to make work in JSFiddle. I'm afraid I cannot help.

Comment: @EricSSH I guess the answer was found useful. Did you try to look at the JSFiddle?

Comment: @MTR any resolve to this? I'm in the same boat as you

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your Header media rule: `bottom:3em;` modifying the 3em in order for the content to fit.

Then add a separate div selector to the rule for your content area:

```
div.printDivContent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top:3em;   //match size of header
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The CSS key "box-decoration-break" would help when set to "clone".
See: [CSS Fragmentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css3-break-20140116/#break-decoration)

You can create a container class around your content with a margin to top and bottom in the size of your header and footer and then set box-decoration-break to "clone" on this container.

```
#content {
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    margin-bottom: 90px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhm I think your should use

```
position:relative
```

instead of

```
position:fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for those of you that are unable to find a reliable way to print headers on the top of all the pages when printing (without overlapping content). I solved this by wrapping the page in a table when printing, and placing my header in the table's header. This isn't the most elegant solution but works (at least in Chrome).

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>
             <!-- Elements you want to appear in the header -->
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <!-- Content that may span multiple pages... -->
          </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```